# MVC Http Post setting values in entity framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, http-post

I have a model patient, which can have 0 or more addresses linked to it.

I only want one primary address, so on my edit/create post I would like to set all other values of 'IsPrimaryAddress' to false.

I have written the following code.

```
    // POST: /Roles/Create
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(Address address)
    {
        using (var context = new WaysToWellnessDB())
        {
            //if address is primary, make all others not
            if (address.IsPrimaryAddress)
            {
                var addresses = context.Addresses.Where(x => x.IsPrimaryAddress == true && x.AddressId != address.AddressId);
                foreach (var item in addresses)
                {
                    item.IsPrimaryAddress = false;
                    item.UpdatedBy = -1;
                    item.UpdatedDate = DateTime.Now;
                }
            }

            address.PatientId = Id;
            address.UpdatedBy = -1;
            address.UpdatedDate = DateTime.Now;

            context.Entry(address).State = EntityState.Modified;
            context.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("View", "Patient", new { @id = Id });
        }
    }
```

However I am getting the following error message:

> Attaching an entity of type 'WaysToWellness.Address' failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value.

Can someone explain why I cannot do this and why it throws an error?

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found the issue.

I think it was because I was trying to set the same address row twice, once in the loop and then once again at the bottom.

The following has fixed the issue.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(Address address)
    {
        using (var context = new WaysToWellnessDB())
        {
            //if address is primary, make all others not
            if (address.IsPrimaryAddress)
            {
                var addresses = context.Addresses.Where(x => x.IsPrimaryAddress == true && x.AddressId != address.AddressId);
                foreach (var item in addresses)
                {
                    item.IsPrimaryAddress = false;
                    item.UpdatedBy = -1;
                    item.UpdatedDate = DateTime.Now;
                }
            }

            address.UpdatedBy = -1;
            address.UpdatedDate = DateTime.Now;

            context.Entry(address).State = EntityState.Modified;
            context.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("View", "Patient", new { @id = address.PatientId });
        }
    }
```

Comment: You've forgot to add `x.PatientId == Id` condition to your where clause

Comment: Sorry I had slightly changed the method to not pass in the patient Id as this wasn't needed, I have update the original post